# Using SAS efficiently to keep code DRY

Tags: sass

I wrote the following code, but I think this can be shorter if I use the full potential of SASS.

**Code:**

```
  &.pos-y-top {
    .dropdown-element {
      top: 0;
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-y-bottom {
    .dropdown-element {
      bottom: 0;
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          top: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-x-left {
    .dropdown-element {
      right: 0;
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          right: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-x-right {
    .dropdown-element {
      left: 0;
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          left: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-x-left.pos-y-bottom {
    .dropdown-element {
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          transform-origin: top right;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-x-left.pos-y-top {
    .dropdown-element {
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          transform-origin: bottom right;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-x-right.pos-y-bottom {
    .dropdown-element {
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          transform-origin: top left;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  &.pos-x-right.pos-y-top {
    .dropdown-element {
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          transform-origin: bottom left;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried yesterday with `@each` but after I finished it the code was just as long as this one.

Could anyone can show me the "smart" way to write code like this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a `@mixin` with parameters and then include it with the values you want. For example,

```
@mixin distances($top: 0, $right: 0, $bottom: 0, $left: 0) {
  .dropdown-element {
      top: $top;
      right: $right;
      bottom: $bottom;
      left: $left;
      .content-wrapper {
        .content, app-dropdown-content {
          top: $top;
          right: $right;
          bottom: $bottom;
          left: $left;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And then you could have:

```
&.pos-y-top {
  @include distances(0, initial, 0, initial);
}
```

This could save several lines. You can put even more parameters. This is just an example.

Comment: Thanks, but because as in example, i need sometimes in dropdown.element a top value and in the content-wrapper not, i need to make for both a single var like: $ele-top: 0, $ele-right: 0, $ele-bottom: 0, $ele-left: 0, $con-top: 0, $con-right: 0, $con-bottom: 0, $con-left: 0

And in this way is it impossible to make the stuff with the transform-origins, because there is no way to give a origin for only Y or X... i need to check 2 classes, and give for every case the transform-origin: XY

Answer (score 0):

I do it now like this, but i am not sure... it looks little dirty and undynamic to me:

```
.dropdown {
  @each $axis, $pos, $originX, $originY in
                  ('y', 'top', 'top', 'right'),
                  ('y', 'bottom', 'bottom', 'right'),
                  ('x', 'left', 'top', 'left'),
                  ('x', 'right', 'bottom', 'left') {
    &.pos-#{$axis}-#{$pos} {
      .dropdown-element {
        @if($pos == 'top') { top: 0; }
        @if($pos == 'bottom') { bottom: 0; }
        @if($pos == 'left') { right: 0; }
        @if($pos == 'right') { left: 0; }
        .content-wrapper {
          .content, app-dropdown-content {
            @if($pos == 'top') { bottom: 0; }
            @if($pos == 'bottom') { top: 0; }
            @if($pos == 'left') { right: 0; }
            @if($pos == 'right') { left: 0; }
            transform-origin: #{$originX} #{$originY};
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was to fast... the transform-origin is totaly wrong, but i am to confused to understand why...